# How to display information form a database about gender user?

Tags: php, mysql

In the database I have a gender table where male is M and female is F. Then I want to display full information about the gender of the user, so if M is to be male, and if F is to be female. The problem is that it always displays Female. Can someone see the code and give a hint where the error lies?

```js
 public function getData()
    {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $sql = $this->database->connect()->prepare("SELECT user.id, first_name, last_name, avatar, birth_date, gender, age, school, work, city, martial_status, number_phone FROM user JOIN user_data ON user.id = user_data.user_id where user.id = :abc and user_id = :abc");
        $sql->bindParam(':abc',$id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sql->execute();

        if($sql->rowcount())
        {
            $row = $sql->fetch();
        }
        $this->userData = $row;
    }

    public function display(string $colName)
    {
        echo (isset($this->userData[$colName])) ? $this->userData[$colName] : '';
    }
```

```html
<main>
<div class='container'>
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xl-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <div id="name"><span><?php echo $profil->display('first_name') ?></span> <span><?php echo $profil->display('last_name') ?></span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <div class="row" id="margin">
                    <div class="col-xl-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <div>Płeć: <?php if($profil->display('gender')=='M'){ echo "Mężczyzna";} else{ echo "Kobieta";} ?></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        </main>
```

Comment: Is the function you call here: `$profil->display('gender')` the same `display` function you show above?

Comment: Yes, that is the same function.

Comment: That function doesn't take any parameters and doesn't return any values.

Comment: I updated the code, now you understand this code ? Last name and first name are displayed correct, but gender not, because I do something wrong with if.

Comment: You've shown another portion of the template. It doesn't explain how the data is fetched. As I pointed out in my previous comment, the function you have shown in the question doesn't take parameters and doesn't return values, so it couldn't show anything. You need to show how this data is fetched from the class.

Comment: Now I change my code, I forgot add function display.

Comment: And there you have it, that function echoes, it does not return. So you can't use it to do comparison - the result of it will always be `null`, so it can't equal `M` (or any other string for that matter).

Comment: So what I can do ?

Comment: You can make it return the value. You'd have to echo in the template then, `echo $profil->display('...')`.

Comment: Ok, the problem is resolved.

Comment: Incidentally, a martial status measures how ready an entity is for war.